# Using an array later in a program results in only displaying one record

Tags: php

I feel silly for asking this, and I am sure it is something very simple. When I try to reference the variable "test" later in a script, instead of listing all 70 items in the array it only lists one.

```
<?php
$exclude = '/^.*\.(lck)$/i'; 
$directory = 'images/slide/';   
$rootpath = 'images/slide/';
$pathnames = preg_grep('/^([^.])/', scandir($rootpath));
shuffle($pathnames);
foreach ($pathnames as $pathname) {
    if (preg_match($exclude, $pathname)) {
      } else {
        $test = '["'.$directory. $pathname.'"]';    
     }
    }
?>
```

If I echo "test" right below the test variable declaration it displays everything correctly. If I echo it out later it only displays one item.

Comment: should this:         $test = '["'.$directory. $pathname.'"]';     be         $test.= '["'.$directory. $pathname.'"]';    ? (concatenation)

Comment: you are only setting `$test` to a string it will only ever be one value as it is not an array, or do you mean to concatenate each next value like Maximus mentions.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you're treating test as a string, trying adding this at the start of your code:

```php
$test = array();
```

And then change:

```php
$test = '["'.$directory. $pathname.'"]';
```

to:

```php
$test[] = $directory. $pathname;
```

Answer (score 0):

On each iteration of the loop, you're overwriting the previously assigned valued of `$test`;

```
$test = '["'.$directory. $pathname.'"]';
```

When you display this, no matter whether straight after assignment or after the loop, you'll get the last assigned value.  If you want to accumulate the values in the variable, you need to append to it, for example,

```
$test .= '["'.$directory. $pathname.'"]';
```

Alternatively, if you want your `$test` to be an array and contain all files in it, then your assignment should be to an array element, not to the whole variable, e.g.

```
$test[] = '"'.$directory. $pathname.'"';
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, if I do this: 
    $test = '["'.$directory. $pathname.'"]';
    echo $test;    
I get the result I am looking for, it lists all 70 items in my array, but if I do this:     
    $test = '["'.$directory. $pathname.'"]';
    } 
    echo $test;    
I get only the one item, even making the changes you suggested.

Comment: @JakeThomas that is because your `echo` statement is being called on each loop, where as your `echo` statement on the outside of the code block is only going to be called once.